# Function that generates a list of all possible lists given the elements a position can take are specified

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell I'm looking for a function with the typing `[[a]] -> [[a]]` that generates a list such as `[[1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,1,3], [1,2,1], [1,2,2], [1,2,3]]` given the parameter `[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]`. The function should generate a list of all possible lists given that each element can take some certain values. So for the above example, in all possible lists the first element can take any value in `[1]`, the second can take any in `[1,2]` and the third can take any `[1,2,3]`. Each list should be the same size as the number of lists in the list passed in as the parameter (which in the above case is 3, since there are three lists in `[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]`).

To achieve this I've looked in to the `replicateM` function, but this assumes each element can take the same number of values. Is there a function where you can specify that different elements can take different values? If there isn't, what would a function that achieves this look like?

Comment: This function is known as the **cartesian product** of lists.

Comment: `\i -> replicateM i` == `\i -> sequence . replicate i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is

```
sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

specialized to lists, i.e. `(f ~ [], t ~ [])`, yielding

```
sequenceA :: [[a]] -> [[a]]

> sequenceA [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3]]
```